# Resizing Image to fit Imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

I've look at MANY questions on Stackoverflow and tried many workaround but it still didn't work.

What I wanna achieve :

[image]
[image]

Yet I am achieving this :

[image]

This is my current xml code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve this is to scale the image (bitmap) using a Matrix.

An alternative is to use a library I previously created which does this for you:

https://github.com/laurencedawson/ZoomableImageView

This will automatically scale the image to fit the screen and also add pinch to zoom.

Comment: How do I go about using it? Is there any tutorials or example codes? Because I'm using it to load images in listview with lazyload class. Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry didn't realise you were using a listview, might not be the best option (due to the vertical scrolling).

If you take a look at the drawing and scaling code it should help you out.

Answer (score 3):

add

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/text"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
```

Answer (score 1):

CenterInside, Resize Image According To view dimensions and its Resolutions. So if an Image Has size of 300*450 and we have set this image to an imageview of scale type centerinside, with dimensions 200*400, then it will make size of image to 200*300, According to the target dimensions, so scaling it down make 200 is minimum in width and height. I hope I am clear enough. In cases where you need to set dimensions of exact size use FItXY, as suggested by Adeel.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it inside the XML file right?

```
<ImageView  
android:layout_width="size of image (in density pixels)"  
android:layout_height="size of image (in density pixels)" />
```

so for example:

```
<ImageView  
android:layout_width="60dp"  
android:layout_height="60dp" />
```